# character is completely black in render

Tags: rendering

In solid mode my character has all their details and colors on, but when I switch to render, the character goes completely black regardless of the light. How do I fix this?

[image: 3D and render view]

[image: node setup]

Comment: Wont be bad if you show us more information, like the node setup, for example.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me  TheMadTomato1209. iv added a picture of the node.

Comment: This looks like a different issue since Mat Preview looks to work somewhat.  I'm voting to reopen.